# Syntax of Model Key Path - Bindings xcode 5.1.1

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

Hey I am new to mac development and I want to use bindings (xcode 5.1.1).

I want to set the Title of a radio button dynamically by an entry of an array controller. I am looking for something like a syntax description how I can perform it.

e.g. something like  value1 WHERE value2="bla"

If I trying to search at google I always find solutions which did it programmatically.

Is there anywhere some examples which show me the syntax I can use in this field?

The picture below should you show what I mean.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. I think you misunderstand the purpose of bindings. There is no conditionality of the sort you describe. What should be the title of the button if value2 is not "bla"? Basically, the key path names a property or series of properties on the model object. That's it; it just names properties. The value of those properties determines the value of the bound attribute of the button (title, in this case).

Comment: I recognized that what I a doing was the wrong way. Actually what I wanted to know is, how I can tell my Array Controller which Entity is selected by my radio group. I can not find an tutorial or example how to do this only with the xcode 5 interface. So without writing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question as clarified in the comments…

First, bindings is not always the right technology. It can simplify some things, but it can't do everything and even for some of the things that it can do, it doesn't necessarily make them simpler.

Radio buttons are often organized in an `NSMatrix`. In that case, you can bind the matrix bindings to track the selection. There are three content-related bindings for a matrix, which can be kind of confusing. The "content" binding is the base. In some cases, it's sufficient. However, if there's a distinction between the object being bound and the value that should be shown by the cells of the matrix, then you can bind the "contentValues" binding to be a subpath of the content binding. That is, it needs to be the same as the content binding with possibly additional elements added to the end of the model key path.

Furthermore, if you want the selected object to be distinct from the content object, you can bind "contentObjects" to a subpath of the content binding.

For example, there may be an array controller whose content is a bunch of `Person` objects. The matrix `content` binding might be bound to that array controller's `arrangedObjects`. If you leave it like that, the cells of the matrix will be populated from the `description` of each `Person` object. However, you could bind the matrix's `contentValues` to the array controller, `arrangedObjects`, model key path `fullName`. Then, the matrix cells will be populated with the full name of each `Person` object.

If you then bind the matrix's `selectedObject` binding to a property on your window controller, that property will be set to the selected `Person` object each time the matrix selection changes. If you would prefer, you could bind the matrix's `contentObjects` binding to the array controller, `arrangedObjects`, model key path `uniqueID`. In that case, the window controller property would not be set to the selected `Person` object itself, but to its `uniqueID` property.

Alternatively, you could bind the matrix's `selectedIndex` binding to a controller property. If you use the window controller, then that just directly sets a property on the window controller to indicate the index of the matrix's selection. Or you could bind it to the array controller's `selectedIndex` property, in which case the selection is "stored" in the array controller.

Comment: Thanks. I used selectedIndex and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need a keypath that takes no parameter as described in the [key-value coding (KVC) reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html)

By binding to an array controller's selection, if the selection collection is one object with a property or method "value1," then the binding runtime is calling the method `valueForKeyPath:@"value1"`.

The [NSObject protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCFACCF) has `performSelector:withObject`, but there is nothing like `valueForKeyPath:withObject` in the [KVC protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) or the [NSKeyValueBindingCreation protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002048-BCICHGHC)

That said, [registering dependent keypaths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html) can provide some equivalent behavior...

```
+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue1 
{ 
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"value2",nil]; 
}
```

... and that would ensure that any time value2 changes, the binding to value1 is re-evaluated.